# Is redundancy ok in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, redundancy

Say I have the following types in my schema:

```
type Deposit { timestamp, ... }

type Withdrawal { timestamp, ... }

type Cancellation { timestamp, ... }
```

There's a page in my app where I display the transaction history. Since there's no rule enforcing the order of transactions (except for the first deposit, of course), I can't know the chronological order in advance, even if each type has a `timestamp` property.

Now, I could write a sorting algorithm, but I'd avoid adding complexity to my codebase.

So I thought about doing this:

```
type History { transactionType }
```

Where `transactionType` is either "Deposit", "Withdrawal" or "Cancellation".

But of course, this comes at the expense of redundancy on my server. Is this good GraphQL practice?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question fully but this looks like a use case for a [union or interface type](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#interfaces). All three types could implement a `Transaction` interface. Also it seems like you have to sort the transactions anyways either in the frontend or in the backend. For me GraphQL is about moving some complexity back into the backend. I think this is a good thing and you should not shy away from it.

Comment: Thanks @Herku, I didn't know about Unions. Seems to be just what I was looking for.

Comment: Amazing, I'm happy to help!